# How to Update AccountContactRelation table of a Contact

Tags: apex, update, accountcontactrelation

I am trying to update a Contact's(Primary) AccountContactRelation object with a list of Accounts that are from a list of selected Contacts(accounts tied to them). Here is my approach:

```
public Contact updateRelatedOrganizations(List<Contact> selectedConts, Contact primaryContact){
    List<Account> selContAccs = new List<Account>();
    Map<Id, Account> primaryContACRMap = new Map<Id, Account>([SELECT Id FROM Account Where Id In (SELECT AccountId FROM AccountContactRelation WHERE ContactId =: primaryContact.Id)]);

    System.debug('BEFORE map: ' +primaryContACRMap);
    for(Contact con: selectedConts){
        if(con.AccountId != null){
            selContAccs.add(con.Account);
        }
    }

    if(!selContAccs.IsEmpty()){
        for(Account acct: selContAccs){
            if(!primaryContACRMap.containsKey(acct.Id)){
                primaryContACRMap.put(acct.Id, acct);
            }
        }
    }

    System.debug('AFTER map update: ' +primaryContACRMap);
    if(primaryContACRMap.keySet().size() > 1){
        update primaryContact; //I know this doesn't work, but I am not sure what 
                               //and how I need to update such that I can push new accounts
                               //to the primary contact's ACR table.
    }

}
```

I can see the `primaryContACRMap` second debug log with selected contact's account records, but I am not sure how can I update the Primary contact's ACR table with those records.

Comment: I can't work out what you're trying to do based on your current code and description. Can you go into more detail? What precisely do you want this code to do?

Comment: Derek, thanks for checking in. I am trying to update the Primary Contact's ACR table with the selected Contacts' accounts. I got the select Contacts' accounts within the Map I had, and I am trying to update that map values to Primary Contact's ACR table.

Comment: That comment was barely sufficient, but I think I'm in your head now (and wrote an answer based on that). For the future, please keep in mind that it's very hard to provide too many details. The more details you provide (to a point), and the better your explanations, the easier other people will find it to answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AccountContactRelation` is a junction table, with lookups (well, master-detail relationship fields, but lookups is shorter to type) to both `Account` and `Contact`.

Based on your description, the purpose of your initial query is to figure out which accounts your "primary" contact is already related to (because trying to add an ACR record to relate a Contact and Account that are already related will result in an error).

Based on that, I think you need another collection to hold the accounts Ids that you want to add your primary contact to that you know are not already related. I'd go with a `Set<Id>`, because duplicates are an issue. Populating this collection should replace your second `for` loop.

Your second loop should still iterate over the `selContAccts` collection, and you will want to still check that the accountId does not exist in your account map. The change is basically just putting the accountId into something other than the map that holds the queried accounts from earlier in your code.

You will need a third collection, and a third loop.
In this loop, you'll iterate over your `Set<Id>` of accountIds, create new ACR records (e.g. `AccountContactRelation acr = new AccountContactRelation(AccountId = newAcctId, ContactId = primaryContact.Id);`)

Store those in a list, and insert after the loop.

Comment: Well, I understood the actual implementation now. I did followed your approach and accomplished what I required. Down-votes doesn't matter for me. If one didn't understood, he/she should ask the way you did. It's a great help from you, I really appreciate your time. :)